# Функция range в Python

Tags: python, функции, range

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите, пожалуйста, как списки связаны с функцией range? Неясно написанное:"По  умолчанию  функция range создает  последовательность  чисел,  которая  увеличивается на  1  для  каждого последующего числа в списке" (см. скрин). И на втором скриншоте смутила запись "второй аргумент (10) —  это конечный предел списка. "

Comment: Списки никак не связаны с `range`.

Comment: Попробуйте `print(*range(10))` чтобы понять написанное.

Comment: Я тоже понимаю, что не связаны. Получается, в книге ошибка....Не могу уловить логику: при чём здесь упоминание списков....

Comment: Бывает ведь и просто список, не только структура данных в Python.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ввела вашу подсказку. Вывело на экран: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. А я сегодня писала print(range(5)) и мне выдавало range(0, 5), только больше сомнений возникало....

Comment: Читайте сразу два учебника. Где они не совпадут, там неточность или ошибка.

Comment: Читаю одновременно несколько учебников. Однако в некоторых учебниках опущены моменты, по которым возникают вопросы....Буду искать больше литературы)))

Comment: У питона отличная, бесподобная документация: [Ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам. Ознакомлюсь с документацией!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Предисловие:*

Учитель ученику: **«Напиши все числа от 1 до 100!»**

- *Никакой труд для учителя* произнести это — он употребил только **2 числа**,
- но *большой труд для ученика* — он должен написать **100 чисел**.

---

Чтобы понят смысл существования объектов типа `range` и что это за объект, пусть нам нужен огромный список всех четных чисел от 10 до 10 миллионов.

Да, вы можете эго задать как

```
lst = [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, ..., 10_000_000]
```

но вместо трех точек вам придется написать всех почти **5 миллионов** четных чисел вручную.

- `range(10, 10_000_001, 2)` намного короче.
- `range(10, 10_000_001, 2)` не список, он **не занимает** в памяти почти **5 миллионов** ячеек (см. дальше).
- `range(10, 10_000_001, 2)` только **рецепт**, как получить **одно единственное** число — сначала первое (**10**), затем второе (**12**) за тем третье (**14**), и т.д., опять экономя памятью.
- `range(10, 10_000_001, 2)` знает, когда *уже не выдавать дальнейшее число* (после числа
  **10 миллионов**, т.е. **перед** достижением предела).
  Вы бы могли в качестве предела использовать даже число `10_000_002` и ничего бы не изменилось.

Ну а теперь возникает вопрос — как заставить объект типа `range()` **чтобы эго рецепт начал работать**, т.е. постепенно выдавать дальнейшее и дальнейшее число?

1. Использовать его как параметр стандартной функции (конструктора) `list()` или `tuple()`.
   Тогда **он** (объект типа `range`) *с огромной скоростью сделает за вас то, что бы вы должна была сделать вручную,* как я намекнул в начале этого ответа:

   ```
   lst = list(range(10, 10_000_001, 2))        # [10, 12, ..., 10_000_000]
   ```

   или

   ```
   tpl = tuple(range(10, 10_000_001, 2))       # (10, 12, ..., 10_000_000)
   ```

   Но для такого огромного количества чисел это неразумно — таким образом бы вы *потеряли главное преимущество* объекта типа `rangе`, т.е. экономностью памятью.
2. Применить его в цикле `for`:

   ```
   for i in range(10, 10_000_001, 2):
   ```

   В памяти будет всегда **только одно число** — текущее значение переменной `i`.

Comment: Cупер! Спасибо!

Comment: @PYTHON_KA, не стоит. :-)